# Performance decays exponentially when inserting bulk data into grails app

Tags: performance, grails, grails-orm, bulkinsert

We need to seed an application with 3 million entities before running performance tests.
The 3 million entities should be loaded through the application to simulate 3 years of real data.

We are inserting 1-5000 entities at a time. In the beginning response times are very good. But after a while they decay exponentially.

We use at groovy script to hit a URL to start each round of insertions.

1. Restarting the application resets the response time - i.e. fixes the problem temporally.
2. Reruns of the script, without restarting the app, have no effect.

#### We use the following to enhance performance

1) Cleanup GORM after each 100 insertions:

```
def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
session.flush()
session.clear()
DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP.get().clear()
```

(old Ted Naleid trick: http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql)

2) We use GPars for parallel insertions:

```
GParsPool.withPool {
    (0..<1000).eachParallel {
        def entity = new Entity(...)
        insertionService.insert(entity)
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- When looking at the log output, I've noticed that the processing time for each entity are the same, but the system seems to pause longer and longer between each iteration.
- The exact number of entities inserted are not important, just around 3 mill, so if some fail we can ignore it.
- Tuning the number of entities at a time have little or no effect.

#### Help

I'm really hoping somebody have a good idea on how to fix the problem.

#### Environment

- Grails: 2.4.2 (GRAILS_OPTS=-Xmx2G -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m)
- Java: 1.7.0_55
- MBP: OS X 10.9.5 (2,6 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3)

Comment: The pausing would make me think it's the JVM doing garbage collection. Have you used a profiler such as VisualVM to see what time is being spent doing garbage collection? Also, it's far better to load the data directly into the database rather than using your application if you are trying to "seed" the application. Performance wise of course.

Comment: Could also be Hibernate's 2nd-level cache?  Not clear whether you're using Hibernate 3 or 4 (slight default config variations) A few other tips here: http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html

Comment: Crazy question, how about not going through the ui?  Load the data into the db.  I know it is not a fix, but is this a valid use case for you?

Comment: @brianjohnsen wondering if you found a solution to share? I'm experiencing the exact same exponential slow-down & pausing when doing bulk inserts, and side-loading into the db isn't really an option for us either.

Comment: @Sitati We ended up side-loading it into the db. Wasn't what we really wanted but it came close enough. Had to have DB-admin help tho...

I hven't double-checked but our problem could very well be caused by a memory-leak we discovred later. I would definitely run som diagnostics if I were you. We found it by looking at the heap-dump alone.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore We didn't use your advice at first, but we should have... :-) 
If you answer the question, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pausing would make me think it's the JVM doing garbage collection. Have you used a profiler such as VisualVM to see what time is being spent doing garbage collection? Typically this will be the best approach to understanding what is happening with your application within the JVM.

Also, it's far better to load the data directly into the database rather than using your application if you are trying to "seed" the application. Performance wise of course.

*(Added as answer per comment)*